# How to read a long declaration code in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I don't know what exactly is the type of a variable in C/C++ when the decalaration code is "long/complicated".
For example:

```
int *const pr=&x;
```

How do I read that?

Comment: That's a rather short declaration...?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I'm not sure that duplicate is useful for anybody except language lawyers...

Comment: I added a better post regarding `const` specifically.

Comment: Read the type from right to left. It is a constant pointer to an integer.

Comment: @ChrisMM _"Read the type from right to left. It is a constant pointer to an integer."_ That works in this case but it doesn't work in many cases: https://parrt.cs.usfca.edu/doc/how-to-read-C-declarations.html

Comment: If you have access to a computer that can run `cdecl`, you could give cdecl this input `int *const pr;` to which it should respond `declare V as const pointer to int;`  As somebody pointed out, C++ is characterized by a dysentery-like torrent of punctuation symbols.

Comment: @mevets: Given the declaration in the question, [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org) reports “bad character '='”. So that is not helpful for somebody who does not know what the `=` character does in a declaration.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if they don't know the difference between a declaration and an assignment, the only tool that will help them is a book.   Cdecl is a wonderful thing to remember, even now after 35 years of writing C code, it helps pull apart the scribbling of the disorganized.

Comment: @mevets: `=` in a declaration just after a declarator is not an assignment.

Comment: Maybe focus on trying to help the poor guy.